# How do I make a Swing app that stores all the inputed values into a string?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, draw

I am making an app that draws shapes for the user inputted coordinates. I need to have two input fields which store the inputted numbers into  arrays every time the user hits ENTER and then connects the coordinates to draw lines.

I looked for some swing tutorials and already saw that the best options for this is a JFormatedTextField. I managed to make a lambda method that prints out the nuber when ENTER is pressed, but I don't know how to use the entered value outside of the lambda and also can't make an array in it since I get an error that the variable must be final.so the question is, how do I store the entered values into an array and how do I make it draw a line every time ENTER is pressed?

```
 Number[] values = new Number[5];
 for (int i = 0; i< 5;i++) {
    fieldXbox.addActionListener(e -> {
       System.out.println("Handled by Lambda listener");
       Number coordinateX = (Number) fieldXbox.getValue();
       values[i]= coordinateX;
       System.out.println("coordinateX" + coordinateX);
    });
```

There is supposed to be one input field for the x and one for the y coordinate, and both should be stored into separate arrays which would be iterated to draw lines that connect them.

Comment: Add the action listener to a button that is pressed after both text fields were updated. Add the action listener **once**. Not within a loop. Get the x and y values and make a `new java.awt.Point(x,y)` for each. You can store all point in an array (`Point[]`) or a collection (`List<Point>`)

Comment: Thanks, can I use those Points like coordinates in drawiLine() ? I am still a total noob with swing since this is my first project with it.

Comment: Yes. If the method you use does not accept `Point` you can always use `point.getX()` and `point.getY()`. For more help post [mcve].

Comment: Also : "I get an error that the variable must be final" you can make an array final `final Number[] values = new Number[5];` and change its values within the Action Listener. Alternatively make it a field `private Number[] values = new Number[5];`  (why use number and not int or double ?)

Comment: Number because this is a JFormatedTextField and when I first tried to save it as an int I got an error.

Comment: `((Number)fieldXbox.getValue()).intValue();` returns int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer your question and show you how this can be achieved with below example. These are the changes I've done to your code.

I have used `JTextField` instead of `JFormatedTextField` because `JFormatedTextField` is too complicated for a simple program like this.

I have used `java.util.List` instead of arrays because `List` can change its size dynamically. Which is useful here because user may add many coordinates.

I have written the class `Canvas` where the lines are drawn on.

Please let me know in comments if there's something unclear.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DrawLines {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> xValues = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> yValues = new ArrayList<>();

    JTextField fieldXbox = new JTextField();
    fieldXbox.addActionListener(e -> {
      System.out.println("Handled by Lambda listener");
      Integer coordinateX = Integer.parseInt(fieldXbox.getText());
      xValues.add(coordinateX);
      System.out.println("coordinateX" + coordinateX);
    });

    JTextField fieldYbox = new JTextField();
    fieldYbox.addActionListener(e -> {
      System.out.println("Handled by Lambda listener");
      Integer coordinateY = Integer.parseInt(fieldYbox.getText());
      yValues.add(coordinateY);
      System.out.println("coordinateY" + coordinateY);
    });

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(xValues, yValues);
    canvas.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    JButton drawButton = new JButton("Draw");
    drawButton.addActionListener(e -> canvas.repaint());

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    f.getContentPane().add(fieldXbox, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
    f.getContentPane().add(fieldYbox, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
    f.getContentPane().add(drawButton, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
    f.getContentPane().add(canvas, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 3, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
    f.setBounds(300, 200, 500, 400);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class Canvas extends JPanel {
  private List<Integer> xCoordinates;
  private List<Integer> yCoordinates;

  Canvas(List<Integer> xCoordinates, List<Integer> yCoordinates) {
    this.xCoordinates = xCoordinates;
    this.yCoordinates = yCoordinates;
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (xCoordinates.size() != yCoordinates.size()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Difference in number of x coordinates and y coordinates." +
          " xCoordinates=" + xCoordinates + " yCoordinates=" + yCoordinates);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < xCoordinates.size() - 1; i++) {
      g.drawLine(xCoordinates.get(i), yCoordinates.get(i), xCoordinates.get(i+1), yCoordinates.get(i+1));
    }
    if (!xCoordinates.isEmpty()) {
      g.drawLine(xCoordinates.get(xCoordinates.size() - 1), yCoordinates.get(yCoordinates.size() - 1),
          xCoordinates.get(0), yCoordinates.get(0));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me so much. Can you explain me the conditions for the last for loop that draws the lines? Also, can I just change the array list to an array and make another box which asks the user to input the max number of  lines and then just connect the last and first one since the end result has to be a closed polygon which I have to triangulate (that is my biggest problem)?And is it possible to make a coordinate axis and enable negative coordinates? Thanks

Comment: @NikolaJ, you are welcome. About the last `for` loop. When the execution gets there, we know `xCoordinates` and `yCoordinates` have same number of items (otherwise an `IllegalStateException` would have been thrown in above line). So, in each iteration of the `for` loop, we take 2 coordinates from each `ArrayList` (that means 2 points) and draw a line. Yes, you can add a another text box to get the number of points from user. Then you can use arrays instead of `ArrayList`s.

Comment: @NikolaJ, Yes, you can have negative coordinates also. Then you need to carefully translate the coordinates to points on the panel when you are drawing. (0,0) of panel is at the top-left corner.

Comment: @NikolaJ, another suggestion: I think it's good to show all the user entered coordinates on the UI (may be in a `JList` or `JTable`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, am working on it now. Just one more question (maybe two), I have a field that asks the user how many sides he wants to have and only figured out how to store the data in a list, but I don't think that is good since someone can then change that number later. Is there a way to disable the input box under certain conditions? Also, since there is a known number of sides, I want to connect the last dot to the first (if there are 3 sides, then after 3 points are entered it automatically connects the last and first one and closes the object,

Comment: also, when I enter the last point, I have to enter one more, but instead of drawing to it,  it just connects the last and first poing. I know it has something to do with the (i+1) in the loop, but don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @NikolaJ, to draw a line between last point and first point, you can have an additional `drawLine()` call after the `for` loop (I just added it to my answer).

Comment: @NikolaJ, yes, you can disable "number of sides" text box after user enters a value. For that you can use another button in the UI (button text can be "Start" or "Start entering coordinates"). Like this you have to design the flow of the program.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. Do you know hoiw I can find th center of the canvas? I tried the .getWidth and .getHeight, but I get 0. What should I measure and how?

Comment: @NikolaJ, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods give actual values only after the panel in shown on the UI (e.g. if you add `System.out.println(getWidth());` inside `paintComponent()` it would print the correct value).